# Concurrent run of same queries (every six minutes) locking a PostgreSQL table

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, aws-lambda, locking

We have a AWS Lambda job which runs every 6 minutes, it takes approx 40 seconds to finish. It has 2 delete queries, an insert and an update query in order of accordance. The queries run on a PostgreSQL DB which is an AWS managed RDS service. It has been running fine till now for 4-5 months.

Delete queries:

```
query = """delete from dev.tbl where datetime < (now() - interval '7 DAY')"""

query1 = """delete from dev.tbl where datetime >= (to_CHAR(now() + interval '5 hours 20 minutes','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:00')::timestamp)"""
```

**Note 1:** The second query has got 5 hours 20 mins because Lambda runs in GMT and we want it in IST, and we need to only delete insert the last 10 mins data, hence deleting that.

Now, we introduced two new derived columns in the final table and two new update queries in the Lambda, now the execution time is going beyond 5 mins and hence it is creating lock on the table (the same queries are going for queue and it is ruining the DB performance).

The insert and three update queries are big and hence due to compliance issues cannot be shared. The queries are fine and when run independently takes few second, each of them, all added up tables 2-3 mins at max, but when given for a run every 6 mins, after an hour or so the piling up starts.

What should be our approach to solve this?

Comment: May need to adjust the vacuum settings for this table, multiple deletes/updates generate lots of dead rows. Look at partitioning the first delete could be handle with a detach partition.

Comment: You have not shown or described any indication of actual locking.  Look at the lock table (pg_locks) for non-granted locks before deciding you have a locking issue.